# Clear cells that are dependents and have validation lists

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

I need some help.  I'm setting up a spread sheet that has multiple validation lists.  Each validation list has multiple validation lists linked to them (dependents).  When I change the first validation list I need to clear all cells that are dependent on it (if they have a validation list attached).

I'm trying to create a macro that is dynamic enough so I don't need to name ranges (I have too many to do that any way).  Basically if the activecell changes / it has a validation list and has dependents - then clear the content of the dependent cell if they have validation lists in them.  In principal it sounds straight forward but it's killing me...!!!!  Does anyone have such a macro already in place or I would be grateful for any advise?  Thanks Ciaran.

Principal Ideas.

Use a dynamic range
    byval target as range

If the cell has dependents
    activecell.dependents.count>0

If the actual cell has a validation list etc.
    activecell.specialcells(xlcelltypeallvalidation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will only look within the current worksheet but could be extended to loop through all worksheets. It also only checks for Validations of type List.

```
Sub ClearListValidations()
    Dim ws As Worksheet    'not used currently
    Dim rngCurrent As Range
    Dim rngValids As Range
    Dim strLookup As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim varIntersect As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set rngCurrent = ActiveCell
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngValids = rngCurrent.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    On Error GoTo 0     'reinstate error handling
    If rngValids Is Nothing Then Exit Sub   'no list validations

    For Each rng In rngValids
        If rng.Validation.Type = 3 Then     'list validation
            Set varIntersect = Application.Intersect(rngCurrent, _
                Range(Mid(rng.Validation.Formula1, 2)))
            If Not varIntersect Is Nothing Then
                rng.ClearContents
                rng.Validation.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next rng
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Essentially, if the List-Validation's source intersects with the current cell, it removes the content and validation settings from the cells.

The `MID()` function is used because `Formula1` includes an equals-sign, and we need to discard this to form a Range.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Andrew.  Comments are very handy for understanding approach.  Greatly appreciated - cheers.

Comment: You are welcome @user1624926. The MID() function is used because Formula1 includes an equals-sign, and we need to discard this to form a range.